# What does construction appendices and shockproof socket mean?

Tags: word-meaning

I am translating a user manual of a wine cooler and I found some expressions that I don't understand. Could you please give me a definition or description?

1. expression

> Do not install this appliance in areas that are too humid or too cold, such as the **construction appendices**, garages or wine cellars.

I dont understand what construction and appendix means together. Does it have something to do with a construction area?

2. expression

> Always use a correctly installed **shockproof socket**.

Cambridge Dictionary says that a *shockproof watch or other device is not easily damaged if hit or dropped.* In case of a socket I think shockproof means that the socket is properly grounded. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Shockproof socket` is almost certainly a [Ground Fault Circuit Interrupter (GFCI)](https://www.osha.gov/SLTC/etools/construction/electrical_incidents/gfci.html), as required by most electrical codes world-wide for safety, particualry in damp locations such as bathrooms, kitchens and where there is direct contact with the ground (e.g. basements and outdoors).

`Construction appendices` *might* refer to an addition to a building, e.g. unheated garage, or perhaps swimming pool area.

The user manual's egregious mangling and misuse of English could result in serious safety hazards!